# My Eclipse luna wont start up what should i do?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/stylesheets/StyleSheet
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getCSSSWTEngine(ThemeEngineManager.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager.getEngineForDisplay(ThemeEngineManager.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1428)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1281)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.stylesheets.StyleSheet cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core_0.10.100.v20140424-2042
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Are you trying to run with Java 9 or later? Luna is far too old to work properly with newer versions of Java and this is one of the errors that occurs.

Comment: `at java.base/...` proves that you are using Java 9 or higher to run your retro Eclipse that you missed to upgrade for more than 6 years which - as greg-449 already said - does not work.